# How to dynamically change the height of a cell in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have:

A `UITableView` in my `UIViewcontroller`

`var searchResults: UITableView  =   UITableView();`

A custom `UITableViewCell` class:

```
class CellSearchResult: UITableViewCell { ... }
```

I register my cell for the tableview:

```
searchResults.registerClass(CellSearchResult.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell");
```

I have my tableView method to fill my table:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellSearchResult
    cell.frame.height = 100;   <<<< ERROR

    ...
}
```

I would like to change the height of my cell like:

```
cell.frame.height = 100;   <<<< ERROR
```

How to do this ?

Comment: You can use the rowheight property of tableView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override `heightForRowAtIndexPath` function. Example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
```

**EDIT:**

If you are not subclassing `UITableViewController`, you can't access tableView functions unless you conform `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource` protocols. You can do this by

```
class myViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate { ....
```

.

```
  tableview.delegate = self
  tableview.datasource = self
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. I guess this is the rigth way, but I have practical issues. When pasting the code into my UIViewcontroller it says "Methode does not override any method...". When removing the override the method is not called. Do I have to add any protocols ? I have to mentoin, that my "func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell" also has no override.

Comment: I have the protocoll UITableViewDelegate in my UIViewcontroller, but my heightForRowAtIndexPath method isn't called.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. I can't reproduce what I have done, but now it works !! Great !

Comment: You need to set UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. Maybe that was causing the problem. You're welcome

Answer (score 1):

If the heights of all cells are the same the most efficient way is to set the [`rowHeight`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/rowHeight) property of the `UITableView` itself.

```
tableView.rowHeight = 100.0
```

> There are performance implications to using
>   tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of rowHeight. Every time a
>   table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
>   on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a
>   significant performance problem with table views having a large number
>   of rows (approximately 1000 or more).

If the cells have variable heights you will need to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var height = // do something to calculate height

    return height
}
```

If you need to do expensive calculations in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` it is also advisable to implement another `UITableViewDelegate` method, [`tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:) (available since iOS 7). Any code you put in this method needs to be efficient.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100.0
}
```

> Providing an estimate the height of rows can improve the user
>   experience when loading the table view. If the table contains variable
>   height rows, it might be expensive to calculate all their heights and
>   so lead to a longer load time. Using estimation allows you to defer
>   some of the cost of geometry calculation from load time to scrolling
>   time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping and the good explanation, but Arda Keskiner was first. upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the following to increase a particular row height at run time without calling the `reloadData()`

Example to increase height of row 10:

```
 rowHightUpdateReqd = true
 tableView.beginUpdates()
 tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 10, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
 tableView.endUpdates()

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

   var rowHight: CGFloat = 50

   if rowHightUpdateReqd == true{
      rowHight = 100
      rowHightUpdateReqd = false
   }
   return rowHight
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping and the good explanation, but Arda Keskiner was first. upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
 return 100.0;   
}
```